# Create an issuance and a send within the same block (XCP)

Tags: utxo, counterparty

Using counterparty api I am issuing an asset, signing the raw transaction and sending raw transaction. Api I used is http://counterparty.io/docs/api/#create_issuance

As it takes 10 or more minutes to confirm the transaction, is it possible to send the unconfirmed transaction using create_send? Or is it possible to automate from counterparty to send it after confirmation? http://counterparty.io/docs/api/#create_send

I have tried the advanced create_ parameters to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried `allow_unconfirmed_inputs: "true"` in subsequent create_send and if yes, what was the error? I'd try that, possibly with `disable_utxo_locks: "true"`, or wait for a while (30s?) before create_send.